# iOS Image Size will not scale up

Tags: ios, image

I have an imageView embedded within a view with a 1:1 ratio constraint and a proportional width constraint set to the super view.  When it is displayed on a device where the resulting width is less than the image's native width it scales down just fine.  However, when it's displayed on a device where the resulting width should be greater than the image's native width it does not scale up beyond the native size.  I've tried setting the content mode to Scale to Fill and Aspect Fill, but neither of those fix the issue.   Now I know that I can get around the issue by using an image whose native size is bigger than max size I'd ever need, but I want to understand why it won't scale beyond the native size.

Comment: Do you have the imageview pinned to any edges or using proportional height and width to the super view?

Comment: Which other constraints on the imageView did you set?

Comment: Thanks, it was a complex issue with constraints.  Needed to lower the priority on a vertical constraint and then add a high priority greater than constraint.  It works fairly well now.